# Vim getting stuck after selecting a file in fzf preview

Tags: plugin-coc, plugin-fzf, fzf

My FZF preview window works fine as long as I'm in some small project, with fewer files. But when I'm in some node project with node_modules and a ton of files, after selecting the file I want to jump to my vim is getting stuck. Here is a [link to my vimrc](https://github.com/Nikhil-Wagh/vimrc/blob/prod/vimrc)

**How can I debug the problem with my vim?**

Please see the attached video to understand better "It is getting stuck".
[image]

After this, I have to close the terminal and open up a new one, which is not very productive.

Adding `plugin-coc` tag as I think coc.nvim is also contributing to this issue.

**UPDATE**

I started using nvim

Comment: Might be helpful: [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @d-ben-knoble, in my case I had [`vim-surround`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) in my vimrc which was causing this behaviour I removed that and now is fixed.

Comment: Odd that surround broke things… if it was me at that point i would ditch fzf; surround is awesome. Your vim, obviously… just surprised

Comment: Yeah, surround is awesome. I'll have to debug further to check what exactly in surround is breaking it.

Comment: This looks really wrong: `plug#begin('/Users/xenocide/.vim/autoload')`, you shouldn't use directory `autoload` to store your plug-ins, since `autoload` is used by Vim to implement function namespaces. Just use the default (pass no arguments to `plug#begin()`, which will store them in `~/.vim/plugged`) to make sure you don't create other interference. (Not sure if this was causing that problem, but it's possible it was.)

Comment: (Also make sure you clean the old plug-in directories from `~/.vim/autoload`.)

Comment: Why are you adding `rtp+=/usr/local/opt/fzf` ? You seem to be fully installing it with vim-plug, so why do you have a system directory in your path too? I could see that breaking things if the two versions don't agree with each other...

Comment: I didn't had `Plug 'junegunn/fzf'` in my vimrc earlier. I'll try without it.

Comment: It does seem to have some effect on it. I'm no longer getting stuck on the preview window.
But now the preview window closes if I use the arrow keys, and works properly if I remove `coc.nvim`.